# JavaScript: Execute function only if all items in array are true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this code:

```
// Required fields is an array of objects

required_fields.each(function() {

  // Check each field: If it has no value, do nothing.
  if( !$(this).val() ) {
    return false;
  }

  // If all the fields are there, do something.
  else {
    alert('Doing something.');
  }

});
```

I'm sure you can see the problem. Having the `alert` in the `.each()` function causes the alert to trigger for every item in the array. But what I want is to only trigger the event if ALL of the array items have a value—that is, if none `return false`.

What is the correct way to trigger something only if all the array items pass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just implement a little counter for each value.

```
var valueCount = 0;

required_fields.each(function () {
  if (!$(this).val()) {
    return false;
  } else {
    valueCount++; // increment to say has value
  }

});

if (valueCount == required_feilds.length) {
  alert('Doing something.');
}
```

Comment: The reason you keep `return false` is to short circuit.

Comment: @andlrc I know thanks. realised as soon as I edited in so scrapped that little comment. Appreciate the heads-up though!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) which will short circuit when a falsy value is returned:

```
var isTrue = [].every.call(required_fields, function(el) {
  return $(el).val();
});

if (isTrue) {
  console.log('Doing something');
}
```

I don't think you have an array but a jQuery object which is array like (got length and `0`, `1`, ... properties) So you can (ab)use the native Array prototype by setting the context with `.call`:

```
var every = Array.prototype.every;
every.call({ '0': 'a', '1': 'b', length: 2 }, console.log.bind(console));
// will output
// ['a', 0]
// ['b', 1]
```

Now that I think of it `jQuery.fn.each` will also short circuit if `false` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Two main options stand out:
1: Write a simple function that takes an array of jQuery objects and returns true if all items in the array have value

```
var allHaveValue = function(array){
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(!$(array[i]).val()){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};

// For your example
if(allHaveValue(required_fields)){
    // Proceed
} else{
    // Handle errors   
}
```

The other alternative is doing the same thing but using the underscore.js function for [every][1]

[1]: http://underscorejs.org/#every which does the same thing. The call would look like:

```
var allHaveValue = _.every(required_fields, function(item){
    return $(item).val();
});

if(allHaveValue)}{
    // Proceed
} else{
    // Handle errors
}
```